# Xamarin NetStandard SfListview Item tapped event not firing?

Tags: xamarin.forms, syncfusion, .net-standard

This is just as the title suggests. I've updated my Xamarin Forms project to a 1.6 NetStandard project and now the tapped event on my SfListView isn't working (It just doesn't fire at all).

Does anyone has any suggestions of what could be wrong or have faced anything like this?

**EDIT**

this is xaml code for SfListView:

```
<StackLayout HeightRequest="15" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <xForms:SfListView Orientation="Horizontal" ItemSize="128" ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}" SelectionBackgroundColor="Transparent" IsScrollBarVisible="False">
       <xForms:SfListView.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <cells:CategoryCell />
          </DataTemplate>
       </xForms:SfListView.ItemTemplate>
       <xForms:SfListView.Behaviors>
          <behaviors:SfSelectedItemBehavior Command="{Binding FilterCommand}" />
       </xForms:SfListView.Behaviors>
    </xForms:SfListView>
</StackLayout>
```

this structure was working before the update. I use a behavior for item selection.

Comment: Please don't deface the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have checked with the reported query “SfListView ItemTapped event does not trigger after updating the NetStandard Library” from our side. Unfortunately the reported issue does not occur at our end and the ItemTapped event is fired as expected.

For your reference, we have attached the working sample link below.

Sample link: http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/190562/ze/SfListViewSample-670965361

Can you please check in your device whether the issue reproduces in our sample also?
If so, Can you please share the below details?

- Whether the reported issue occurs in particular device or all devices? (Can you please share the details of your tested device)
- Whether the issue is produced in particular platform?
- Whether the issue is produced in particular version of Xamarin.Forms and SfListView? (In our sample, we used XForms (v2.3.4.280) and SfListView(v15.3.0.33))

Also can you please share the share the template in which the SfListView items are loaded?